# How can I measure an element without introducing side effects?

Tags: wpf, layout, measure

How can I ask a control to compute it's minimum size requirements but without having any affect on it's current state or future layouts?

For example, say I have a StackPanel in a Grid. The StackPanel's Width will stretch to the size of the grid's Width. But how could I compute the StackPanels minimum Width without affecting anything.

Looking at the Measure method, it says `'Updates the DesiredSize of a UIElement. Calling this method constitutes the first pass (the "Measure" pass) of a layout update.'`

So this approach has side effects.

Comment: Could you explain your scenario? Maybe there is another way to achive your final result.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe that it's possible to do this in WPF. I have wanted the exact same ability (to measure given a constraint w/o inducing a full Measure/Arrange pass.

One experiment I did was to save the current DesiredSize, then InvalidateMeasure followed by UpdateLayout and then Measure and look at DesiredSize.  Then set redo this with the old/saved size.  Unfortunately it's slow and there's a bad side effect in our application which is that UpdateLayout() will run the event loop to process layout events. This can result in reentrancy and processing of other, unrelated queued events which I was not expecting until after the measurement work was complete. Chaos ensues. In short, this is IMO a design decision (flaw?) in WPF.  I've opened a [UserVoice request](https://wpf.uservoice.com/forums/40688-general/suggestions/7101890-allow-an-updatelayout-without-a-nested-message-eve) pleading for the ability to measure layouts w/o the event processing. I predict it'll never happen.

I have resorted to using a hidden window with an instance of the control I'm interested in with no content (ex. and empty button). I do an UpdateLayout when it's safe and grab the desiredsize as the 'empty' size. I use that size as part of calculations later. I use TextFormatter and GenericTextParagraphProperties to measure text myself the same as a TextBlock does. Very ugly code just to avoid a message loop and to leave controls unaffected!  It's also fragile b/c a template change will invalidate my calculations. Luckily, I control the template completely for the controls I need to measure.

Answer (score 0):

You might perform your own calculation based on code provided by microsoft eg. StackPanel: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/Stack.cs,9ef706576207e5a6,references

However StackPanel uses Measure of their children to calculate its own DesiredSize so it might be a struggle to calculate that all by yourself.
I think you should provide more information why you don't want to affect current state. What is wrong with setting DesiredSize of UIElement?

Comment: I can only guess whether @wforl has the same reasons, but I can easily imagine situations where I just want to know the size of a layout without actually imposing/displaying that layout. For example, a UI might be able to arrange controls in various alternative layouts and to do so, it would pick the one that best fits in the available space. Actually changing the sizes to each layout and then measure sounds like quite an untidy solution (and it might even come with ugly visual artifacts such as flickering through of the temporary layouts before the final layout is established).

Answer (score 0):

I think best you can achieve here is calling Measure method. It does have side effects, but if you call it multiple times, only the last state remains valid. You don't have to worry about visual artifacts such us flickering trought temporary layouts. Only the last one will be rendered.